# How to derive date from non-date columns using regex or index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe and dict like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'subject_id':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'age':[42,56,75,48,39],
    'date_visit':['1/1/2020','3/3/2200','13/11/2100','24/05/2198','30/03/2071'],
    'a11fever':['Yes','No','Yes','Yes','No'],
    'a12diagage':[36,np.nan,np.nan,40,np.nan],
    'a12diagyr':[np.nan,np.nan,2091,np.nan,np.nan],
    'a12diagyrago':[6,np.nan,9,np.nan,np.nan],
    'a20cough':['Yes','No','No','Yes','No'],
    'a21cough':[np.nan,'Yes',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
    'a22agetold':[37,np.nan,np.nan,46,np.nan],
    'a22yrsago':[np.nan,6,np.nan,2,np.nan],
    'a22yrtold':[np.nan,2194,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]

 })
df['date_visit'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_visit'])
disease_dict = {'a11fever' : 'fever', 'a20cough' : 'cough','a21cough':'cough'}
```

This dataframe contains info about patients' medical conditions and date of diagnosis

But as you can see that **date of diagnoses is not directly available** and we have to derive it based on columns that contain keywords like `age`,`yr`,`ago`,`diag` which appear within the next 5-6 columns from the condition column (ex : `a11fever`). Look for the next 5 columns after this condition column and you will be able to get the info required for deriving the date.Similary for other conditions like `cough`

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

I was trying something like below but it didn't help

```
df = df[(df['a11fever'] =='Yes') | (df['a20cough'] =='Yes') | (df['a21cough'] =='Yes')]  
# we filter by `Yes` above because we only nned to get dates for people who had medical condition (`fever`,`cough`)
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
df['diag_date'] =  df["date_visit"] - pd.DateOffset(years=df.filter('age'|'yr'|'ago'))  # doesn't help throws error. need to use regex here to select non-na values any of other columns
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['condition', 'diag_date'], i='subject_id', j='grp').sort_index(level=0)
df.melt('subject_id', value_name='valuestring').sort_values('subject_id')
```

Please note that I know the column names of diseases before hand (refer the dict). What I don't know is the actual column name from where I can get the required info to derive the date. But I know that it contains keywords like `age`,`ago`,`yr`,`diag`

`diag_date` is obtained by subtracting the `derived date` from the `date_vist` column.

**Rule screenshot**

[image]

For ex: `subject_id = 1` visited hospital on `1/1/2020` for fever and he was diagnosed at age `36` (`a12diagage`) or `6` years ago (`a12diagyrago`). we know his current age and date_visit, so we can choose to subtract from any of the column which gives us `1/1/2014`

As you can see, I am not able to find out how to select a column based on regex and subtract it

Comment: `df['date_visit']-pd.to_timedelta(df['a12diagyrago'],unit="Y")`?

Comment: No, if you look at 4th subject, you can see that he doesn't have the value for `a12diagyrago` column but he has value for other column to get the derived date. Hence we need to use regex or index postion

Comment: Its two different symptoms and from your expected output, they are separated. Can't you just do it twice, one for fever and one for cough?

Comment: In real time, I might have more than 100 conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#get of columns with Yes at least one value
mask = df[list(disease_dict.keys())].eq('Yes')
#assign mask back
df[list(disease_dict.keys())] = mask
#rename columns names by dict
df = df.rename(columns=disease_dict).max(axis=1, level=0)
#filter out False rows
df = df[mask.any(axis=1)]
#convert some columns to index for get only years and condition columns
df = df.set_index(['subject_id','age','date_visit'])

#extract columns names - removing aDD values
s = df.columns.to_series()
df.columns = s.str.extract('(yrago|yrsago)', expand=False).fillna(s.str.extract('(age|yr)', expand=False)).fillna(s)

#replace True in condition columns to column names
ill = set(disease_dict.values())
df.loc[:, ill] = np.where(df[ill].values, np.array(list(ill)), None)

#replace columns names to condition
df = df.rename(columns = dict.fromkeys(ill, 'condition'))
```

---

```
#create MultiIndex - only necessary condition columns are first per groups
cols = np.cumsum(df.columns == 'condition')
df.columns = [df.columns, cols]
#reshape by stack and convert MultiIndex to columns
df = df.stack().rename(columns={'age':'age_ill'}).reset_index().drop('level_3', axis=1)
#subtract ages
df['age_ill'] = df['age'].sub(df['age_ill'])
#priority yrago so yrago is filling missing values by age_ill
df['yrago'] = df['yrago'].fillna(df['yrsago']).fillna(df['age_ill']).fillna(0).astype(int)
df = df.drop(['yrsago','age_ill'], axis=1)

#subtract years
df['diag_date1'] =  df.apply(lambda x: x["date_visit"] - pd.DateOffset(years=x['yrago']), axis=1)
#replace years
mask1 = df['yr'].notna()
df.loc[mask1, 'diag_date'] = df[mask1].apply(lambda x: x["date_visit"].replace(year=int(x['yr'])), axis=1)
#because priority yr then fillna diag_date by diag_date1
df['diag_date'] = df['diag_date'].fillna(df['diag_date1'])

df = df.drop(['diag_date1','age','date_visit','yr','yrago'], axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
   subject_id condition  diag_date
0           1     fever 2014-01-01
1           1     cough 2015-01-01
2           2     cough 2194-03-03
3           3     fever 2091-11-13
4           4     fever 2190-05-24
5           4     cough 2196-05-24
```

Comment: Fantastic thought process to translate this into code. and thank you for being kind to help me understand the code as well.

Comment: Hi, I had an issue with the dates. details in chat window

Comment: @SSMK - Can you send me link to chat?

Comment: Hi, can you let me know what does `level=0` or `level=-1` do in `df.rename(columns=disease_dict).max(axis=1, level=0)`. I know that max aggregates the `same column names into one`. But what does `level=0 or level=-1` mean

Comment: when I just do `df.rename(columns=disease_dict).head()`, certain columns which has `NaN` as value become `None` when I do `df.rename(columns=disease_dict).max(axis=1, level=0)`. Why is it so?

Comment: @SSMK - yop, I try explain. Idea is after `df.rename(columns=disease_dict)` get duplicated columns names - in sample 2 columns called `cough`. But you are interesting if column has True in one or another one. So if use `max(axis=1, level=0)` it means give all duplicated columns and aggregate max - so if in both columns are at least one True, it retur True, if both False, it return False.

Comment: @SSMK - I create sample data for better understanding `df = pd.DataFrame({
     
         'cough':[True,False,True,False],
         'C':[True,True,False,False],
         'D':[1,3,5,7],

    
}).rename(columns={'C':'cough'})

print (df)


print (df.max(axis=1, level=0))`

Comment: Yes, I got this. but can you help me with this? `level=0 or level=-1` But what does level=0 or level=-1 mean

Comment: @SSMK - it means if there is MultiIndex in columns, then use first `level=0` or last `level=-1` index. Here I think it should be omit, because no MultiIndex in columns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201927/discussion-between-ssmk-and-jezrael).